# How to set up alert for a mail folder in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1

I want to have alert for a specific folder in one of my mail boxes. Would that be possible?

I did look around but could not find a way!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is currently not possible to set custom alerts to specific email folders.

You should consider adding this feature to the suggestions on http://windowsphone.uservoice.com.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make an alert, but you can pin the folder to your start screen, near the top.  That way you'll see it every time you use your phone.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that however I need alert for it, anyways I suggested it to Microsoft.